# Kotlin Multiplatform project include cocoapod dependency

Tags: kotlin, cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform

Trying to setup cocoapods for my Kotlin MPP:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.5.10"
    kotlin("native.cocoapods") version "1.5.10"
    id("com.android.library")
    id("maven-publish")
}
```

Syncing the project ends up in this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':podspec'.
> this and base files have different roots: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\wrap6957loc\gradlew and G:\Workspace\tracking-lib.
```

I am on windows and always will be. The project should build on Windows and Mac. So I assume basic inclusion of that plugin should work?

What can I do to fix the paths?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug. The plugin should be disabled, but the build should be working fine. Please consider reporting it to https://kotl.in/issue

The cocoapods plugin strongly relies on pre-installed components, such as Xcode CLI Tools, cocoapods and cocoapods-generate. All of them are described [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-cocoapods.html#install-the-cocoapods-dependency-manager-and-plugin). The iOS targets of the Kotlin MPP project themselves can't be built on Windows, this is a restriction of the compiler. See a full list of targets and their availability [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mpp-supported-platforms.html).